# How does PyROOT change the python interpreter?

Tags: python, root-framework

If I try to run `.ls` in python, not surprisingly I get a SyntaxError

```
>>> .ls
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    .ls
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But if I import PyROOT, it somehow makes this syntax legal (and behaves as it does in ROOT, listing the contents of the current file; in the example here I haven't opened any.)

```
>>> import ROOT
>>> .ls
>>>
```

Similarly, `.q` works to quit the Python interpreter after I've imported ROOT, as it does in the normal ROOT interpreter.

How does this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can by found in lib/ROOT.py

there is condition that if not ipython the sys.excepthook is redefined:

```
sys.excepthook = _excepthook
```

which in turn contains stuff like:

```
### RINT command emulation     
------------------------------------------------------
def _excepthook( exctype, value, traceb ):
 # catch syntax errors only (they contain the full line)
   if isinstance( value, SyntaxError ) and value.text:
      cmd, arg = split( value.text[:-1] )

    # mimic ROOT/CINT commands
      if cmd == '.q':
         sys.exit( 0 )
```

or few lines bellow:

```
  elif cmd == '.ls':
     return sys.modules[ __name__ ].gDirectory.ls()
```

and if non of those work it resumes normal handling of things.